# Any idea why and _ character breaks my image loading?

Tags: html

I've got a weird error happening on Chrome, Safari and IE whereby if I have this HTML in the code

```
<img src="./img/advert_abc.jpg" class="banner_image">
```

it won't load it (get a 307 error and not much else)

yet if I take out the _ character images load fine.
E.g.

```
<img src="./img/advertabc.jpg" class="banner_image">
```

I've made sure the images exist on disk and copy/pasted them all around but doesn't matter what I name it, if the filename has a _ character in there it fails.

This works on my local WAMP and remote LAMP stacks.. is there something special about the _ character perhaps?

Whilst I am using javascript/jquery in there too it seems to be a re-creatable error with any image with and without my javascript code creating this img object.

Comment: Did you declare character set in your head to UTF-8?  Not sure if it matters, but worth a try...

Comment: Is there an htaccess or server config using mod rewrite? It a 307 is a temp redirect of sorts so there maybe a if _ matches pattern, redirect to something else.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, Finally found it, was a plugin called 'AdBlock' running in the browsers that was searching for the keyword "advert_"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just closing this answer in case anyone else finds it, was due to AdBlock silently running and doing some redirects with images names 'advert_???' as the filename.